# i cant redirect after getting a response using axios post request in react i tried using Redirect but not able to do it

Tags: reactjs, redirect, axios, response, react-router-dom

So I am trying to redirect using `react-router-dom` component Redirect but I am not able to do it I dont understand why . Pls help me I am a beginner and cant understand what's wrong is happening clearly with the code.

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    const res = await SearchAction(values);
    console.log(res.data);
    setResult(res.data); //this is the response

    <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/search/result', state: { data: `${res.data}` } }} />; //this is the  redirect
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('error searching', err);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem: Improper Placement of `<Redirect/>`

Your code is attempting to render a `Redirect` component inside of an event handler.  This doesn't make sense and won't work.  Event handlers can modify your state but they can't render anything directly.

#### Solution: Conditionally Render `<Redirect/>`

You should render the `Redirect` conditionally based on the current state of your component.  The `Redirect` needs to the returned in the correct place, which is your component's `return` section (or `render()` for a class component).  You want to render the `Redirect` only after the event handler has set its data.  Assuming that your `result` state is initially `undefined`, we can check the value of `result` and see if it has been updated with data.

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const res = await SearchAction(values);
      console.log(res.data);
      setResult(res.data); //this is the response
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error searching", err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {!!result && (
        <Redirect
          to={{ pathname: "/search/result", state: { data: result } }}
        />
      )}
/* ... */
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Passing Through Data

It is not the best idea to pass large amounts of data through the `Redirect`.  In my (very biased) opinion, querying the API should be the job of the search results page.  It would be better to just pass the `values` to your `"/search/result"` page and move the API request into that component.

Comment: Thank you so much it was really helpful. Because i had no clue that you cannot put redirect in a function.